# Aplicacion en Mvc5 asp.net sistema de escuelas

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una aplicacion en mvc 5 asp.net y me gustaria generar unos numero alfanuméricos automáticamente eJ: abcd-001-2018 y que se me registre en la base de datos...

Comment: Hola Bryant, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo **intentado**. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.